# Why is oracle-java8-installer not installing on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: java, installer

I'm trying to install the `oracle-java8-installer` on Ubuntu 18.04, with the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y  && echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Suddenly this started failing:

```
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2019-01-15 21:37:57--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.198.4.45
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.198.4.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2019-01-15 21:37:57--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.34.18.118, 2001:4de0:2204:98::366, 2001:4de0:2204:93::366
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.34.18.118|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547588398_34b19094b1b04e5117af5cb53859faab [following]
--2019-01-15 21:37:58--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547588398_34b19094b1b04e5117af5cb53859faab
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.198.4.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547588398_34b19094b1b04e5117af5cb53859faab [following]
--2019-01-15 21:37:58--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547588398_34b19094b1b04e5117af5cb53859faab
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.198.4.45|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-01-15 21:38:00 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Has this file recently been deleted or moved?

Comment: "Has this file recently been deleted or moved?" - It most likely does not exist; You received a 404 error.  Can you download the [tar.gz](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz) on another machine, through your browser?

Comment: This may be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966107/cant-install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I can almost guarantee you, that Oracle simply archived, Java 8 u191.  Java 8 is currently at update 201.  Which was the case for the linked question, since your attempt to use `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub` which was retired a while ago

Comment: Yeah I'd agree that's what happened as well

Answer (score 1):

We can download the java manually and install it very easily.

Download the java 8 version: [`jdk-8u212-linux-x64.tar.gz`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Steps to Install:

```
  sudo mkdir /usr/local/java

  sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u212-linux-x64.tar.gz

  sudo mv jdk1.8.0_212 /usr/local/java/

  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/javac" 1

  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java" 1

  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/javaws" 1

  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
  sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_212
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Check the version once installation got successful.

```
sudo java -version
```